# SVN Log show other than username

Tags: svn, active-directory

My company recently changed our policies so we now all have obfuscated login ID's.  Instead of something nice and readable my SVN commits now say u839212.  Is there any way we can change the SVN log to print names instead of user ID's?  We are using active-directory with SVN which is where the login information is coming from.  The information we want is in active-directory and I can get it, I just don't know how to get SVN to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN can't display it on its own. You will need to write your own program to parse the output of `svn log` and query AD to do the translation. This is easier if you use the `--xml` switch as you won't have to do as much text parsing - you can use XML parsing libraries instead, which will be much easier.

Side note: your company's new policy makes me sad.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it internal to SVN, alas you confirmed my worry.

Edit: The policy is quite... annoying.  We cannot figure out what the benefit is.